MPLabX MCC - Text glitchy and unreadable
I've recently installed MPLabX IDE and I'm trying to use it. I'm quite familiar with both the IDE and the MCC, as I've been using them for over a year now (on my company's PCs though).
But at home, impossible to work with the MCC, as the text appears to be glitchy as hell and unreadable:
What I see when I start the MCC: glitchy text.
I tried changing the language and already checked on the internet, but I couldn't find any similar issue. Tried restarting my computer, starting both Harmony and Classic MCCs, but nothing will do so far.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Ok bot, you need to be improved.
